# find the sum of 2 numbers in c with input from user

Tags: c, input, sum, printf, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int num1=0;
int num2=0;
int sum=0;
printf("enter 2 numbers\n");
scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
sum=num1+num2;
printf("%d",&sum);
return 0;
}
```

This is what i am trying but 23+23 is coming out to be 6422292 in this way.I cant find the error. Please help.

Comment: Rishi Gandhi, Why did you code and put a `&` in `printf("%d",&sum);`?

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT put an "address of" operator (`&`) on this line:

```
printf("%d",&sum);
```

It should be

```
printf("%d", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey actually the error is in the printf() function

The & is your telling to print the value stored in the sum variable

Make the following changes to your code

```
printf("%d", sum);

Hope you got fixed the error
```

Answer (score -1):

#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

int a , b;

printf ("enter a\n");

scanf ("%d", &a);

printf ("enter b\n");

scanf ("%d", &b);

int sum = a + b;

printf ("the sum is : %d", sum);

return 0;

}

Comment: Try to insert the code in as a code snippet and also please correct the indentation

Comment: And add some text explaining why/how your code answers the question. Code-only answers are generally not preferred here. Also, the question already has 2 answers, so make sure to explain what is unique in your answer.